# Can someone help me in adding Sap ui5 "Quick View"

Tags: sapui5

Iam familiar with adding a fragment in sap UI5 but I was unware how to consume a quick view and consuming  json data in it.

Can someone guide me through this with an example.

Thankyou in Advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What have you tried already and what is the result of your research so far? Have you reviewed the [`sap.m.QuickView` samples](https://sdk.openui5.org/entity/sap.m.QuickView) from the Demo Kit before? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The best way to learn this is to check the official samples of the QuickView https://sdk.openui5.org/entity/sap.m.QuickView